# template error: nontype ".. [with T=T] is not a type name"

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, cross-compiling

Trying to typedef my memory alignment I came out with the following construct (which still is a bit of work in progress because I need to correct the GNU version):

```
#if defined(__GNUG__)
template <typename T>
struct sfo_type {
    typedef T* restrict __attribute__((aligned(32))) aptr32;
};

#elif defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
template <typename T>
struct sfo_type {
    typedef T* restrict __attribute__((aligned(32))) aptr32;
};
#endif
```

and then I try to use it like this:

```
template<typename T>
class tsfo_vector {
private:
   sfo_type<T>::aptr32  m_data;
   int                  m_size;
...
```

but then I get the following error message:

```
/Users/bravegag/code/fastcode_project/code/src/sfo_vector.h(43): error: nontype "sfo_type<T>::aptr32 [with T=T]" is not a type name
 sfo_type<T>::aptr32 m_data;
 ^
```

Can anyone advice what's wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`aptr32` is dependent on `T` so:

```
template<typename T>
    class tsfo_vector {
    private:
        typename sfo_type<T>::aptr32 m_data;
      //^^^^^^^^
```

For further explanation on the use of `typename` see [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Nice, thank you! I am actually puzzled by this one ... how come a data member has to have a typedef marker in front to compile? it is a bit of a weird thing.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua, the answer linked explains the use of `typename` much better than I could.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua: Not the data member, but its type is prefixed with `typedef`.

Comment: The short answer is that even though the compiler may have your definition of `sfo_type`, it's possible that at the point where you use it there will be an explicit specialization (like sfo_type<int>); there is no requirement that specializations have the same members as the general template, so you have to tell the compiler "this name **must be** the name of a type". That's what `typename` does.